Django STATIC_URL value "/static/" vs "static/"?
I'm a junior dev and know how pathing works. I'm wondering what the paths for the directory that static files will be served from are if the values for are STATIC_URL="/static/" and STATIC_URL="static/". I know there is a different since the latter cause my app to not find the static files even though it's the default value. Thank you!

Are you saying that static files cannot be found when STATIC_URL="static/"?

If STATIC_URL = '/static/', Django will serve the static files from the /static/ directory at the root of your domain. For example, if your domain is www.example.com, Django will look for static files at www.example.com/static/.
On the other hand, if STATIC_URL = 'static/', Django will serve the static files from the static/ directory relative to the current URL. This means that if you're on the page www.example.com/blog/, Django will look for static files at www.example.com/blog/static/.
The leading slash in the STATIC_URL setting is very important. It determines whether the path is absolute (starts from the root) or relative (starts from the current URL).

I wasn't aware that the current directory was automatically prepended in the scenario there is no leading slash. Thanks for explaining. I was having issues though even when I was at the root of my website localhost:8000 and had STATIC_URL="static/" when linking to the style sheet as href="{% static '{app name}/style.css' %}", even though it seems like this scenario shouldn't cause an error based on your explanation.

Do you have any reference for this claim?

@ChukwujiobiCanon I'll investigate a bit more and report back or link a repo if I can't figure it out
